# How to pass username after login redirect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

I have 2 applications: one does the login (**app1**) and another one does other stuff that I want (**app2**). The **app1** is built in ASP.NET Boilerplate and what I want to do is after login with this app, I want to redirect to the **app2**. Until now everything is fine, I just used the `returnUrl` parameter to redirect to the **app2**. The problem is that I want to pass to **app2** some of the login information like `username`. It's not supposed to change anything in **app1**, so how can I do that?

Both **app1** and **app2** are built in MVC 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **app1**, the user is available from `loginResult.User` as you can see in [this line](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/0b3d92424f35a675853fff0c09a79fe4a54966b6/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L106):

```
await SignInAsync(loginResult.User, loginResult.Identity, loginModel.RememberMe);
```

You can append the `username` as a query parameter after checking `returnUrl`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
{
    returnUrl = Request.ApplicationPath;
}
else
{
    returnUrl += "?username=" + loginResult.User.UserName; // This line
}
```

And retrieve that in **app2**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer =). I already tested and it works. But if I want to pass the userName as an header? I'm looking to this line **return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });**. How can I change the AjaxResponse Headers?

Comment: I'm not sure, you might be able to access `HttpContext.Current.Response`.

Comment: I already tried, but HttpContext doesn't change anything in the AjaxResponse =(. Btw I didn't find HttpContext.Current, I just tried HttpContext.Response.