# How can I pass parameters using request Header with aspnet boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, aspnetboilerplate

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768765/how-to-get-username-after-login-redirect-is-aspnet-boilerplate/46773632?noredirect=1#comment80495847_46773632) question, now I want to pass the username in the headers of the redirection request. The code is this:

```
return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });
```

Is there some way to do that using this AjaxResponse or something like that?

Comment: you can! but important thing is which method will get this response.

Comment: In returnUrl I will have something like that **http://localhost/Account/Test**. The **Test** will be the method will get this respose.

Comment: You can add custom header to your action response like HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(headerkey, value);

Comment: Yes thank you,  I totally forgot, I will put the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the sugestion of tienguyen and I used `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(headerkey, value);` and it works fine!